# Date not showing correct in php code

Tags: php

Hey guys take a look over this code. This code is showing current month stats,but if i want to check last month stats instead of this month then what changes i need to do in this small code ?

```
$date_time_array = getdate(time());

$last_month = $date_time_array["month"];

$this_year  = $date_time_array["year"];

$last_mon   = $date_time_array["mon"];



$date = mktime(0,0,0,$last_mon,1,$this_year); //The get's the first of March 2009
$links = array();
$newstamp = time() - 3600;
$cpc = 0;
$cpm = 0;
$click = 0;

for($n=1;$n <= date('t',$date);$n++){



$thisdate = $this_year.'-'.$last_mon.'-'.str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

$sql = "select * from pub_st_daily where  user='$user' && STR_TO_DATE(pdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$thisdate'  ";
```

Comment: stack flow is not usefull anymore :/ fake views no help

Comment: This site is not intended for "code for me" questions. Ask a specific question about what has failed about your own attempts to change your code.

Comment: have a look in [the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) on how to get last month. Try "1 months ago".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$date = new DateTime("07/30/2015"); //Will give you July 30th

$date_time_array=getdate($date->format("U"));
...
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e922f38dc231655d50539ecaea953e6f0f277f4e)